# Objective-C, Storyboard: instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier returns nil

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, storyboard

I have a UITableViewController with a storyboard push segue linking from the prototype cell to a detail page, a regular old UIViewController.  In the storyboard, the detail ViewController has an identifier, and the segue has an identifier which is the same as the detail identifier except that the first letter is lowercase.  Furthermore, the detail ViewController has a "custom class" (`AttractionDetailViewController`) selected in the class pulldown.

Doesn't work.  The problem is that `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AttractionDetails` returns `nil`.

Relevant code.  First the `prepareForSegue` method which the debugger has never entered.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"attractionDetails"])
    {
        AttractionDetailViewController *attrDetailVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    }
}
```

Instead it goes into this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //AttractionDetailViewController *attrDetailVC = [[AttractionDetailViewController alloc] init];
    AttractionDetailViewController *attrDetailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AttractionDetails"];

    NSIndexPath *selIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    attrDetailVC.theAttraction = [attractions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:attrDetailVC animated:YES];
}
```

Since `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` returns `nil` it throws an exception of course.  The really interesting thing is, if I use the `alloc init` line instead, it works, but the screen is all black.

Anyway, I've read up about this and tried a few different things and I'm still stymied.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, it is actually.  Which I didn't even think to check because, well, I got to `self` somehow (it's the third view down from the root navigation controller).  I tried this instead and it seems to do the trick: `UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't instantiate your master view controller (the `UITableViewController`) from the storyboard, so its `storyboard` property is nil.

Comment: then please give alternative?
as my master view controller is got by this [[MyViewController alloc] init]
@rob mayoff

Comment: Get your master view controller from the storyboard, or load your new view controller from the storyboard. Look at the [*UIStoryboard Class Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html).